# How can i get only numbers from a file text in c?

Tags: c

### I want to get the only number from a file text but I couldn't do it. Can you help me?
FILE:

Name Surname: Frank Castle

ID number: 123456

Password: 123

Student (1) or officer (2): 1

---

Name Surname: Pete Castiglione

ID number: 789456

Password: 159

Student (1) or officer (2): 2

I want to make a program that can remember person ID number and password from file text when I close and open it again.

Comment: Where is the code (the code that didn't work)?

Comment: consider sharing [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

This will take care of the reading, not sure what your intention is.

```
char id_num[20];
char password[20];
char buff[512]; 
unsigned char *temp_str[64];

FILE *fileptr=NULL;
fileptr = fopen("yourfile.txt", "r");
if (!fileptr)
{
    printf("\nIO read error or whatever");
    break;
}

// get line by line
while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fileptr))
{
    if(sscanf(buff, ("\nID number:=%s"), temp_str) == 1)
    {
        snprintf(id_num, 200 , "%s", temp_str);
    }
    else if(sscanf(buff, "\nPassword:=%s", temp_str) == 1)
    {
        snprintf(password, 20 , "%s", temp_str);
    }
}

fclose(fileptr);
```

Be sure to consider overflow conditions.